# How to add generics to my code

Tags: java, generics

I need to use generics for my `nestList`. What syntax I can use so that both `Integer` and `String` lists can be added to nested lists as well as of any other types ?

```
    // integer list
    List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));

    // string list
    List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz"));

    // nested lists.
    List nestedList = new ArrayList();
    nestedList.add(listInteger);
    nestedList.add(listString);
    nestedList.add("A");
```

Comment: That's exactly the opposite of generics.

Comment: Great question, generics are tough to grasp at first (I struggled quite a bit on them early on when I was first learning OOP).

Comment: So let's back up a step.  Why do you want to store two different types of list in the same type?  What are you attempting to glean from that?

Comment: I second @Makoto's question. Unless you plan to just call `toString()` on everything in the list, it's not going to be very useful.

Comment: I am trying to improve the way I write answers, so could you please give me some feedback? I answered the same thing as user3818514, 1 hour before. Why didn't I get the answer? Was my question too long? Not specific? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the type as Object as you are adding different types of Objects(list,String) into the nestedList.

```
List<Object> nestedList = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

You can also use type as     List only if you are adding list Objects in nestedList.

```
List<List> nestedList = new ArrayList<List>();
```

But this will error out if you try to add nestedList.add("A") , also It will also prompt a warning for using raw types.

Answer (score 4):

Since you want to store lists AND non-collection objects ("A") you should store Objects in your collection, like:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // integer list
        List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));

        // string list
        List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz"));

        // nested lists.
        List<Object> nestedList = new ArrayList<Object>();
        nestedList.add(listInteger);
        nestedList.add(listString);
        nestedList.add("A");
    }
}
```

Just note that `List<Object>` is just to avoid the compiler from complaining that your collection doesn't have a type. Effectively, `List<Object>` and `List` are the same thing.

You could have suppressed the warning using this:

```
import java.util.*;


public class Main {

    @SuppressWarnings({"rawtypes", "unchecked"})
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // integer list
        List<Integer> listInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(1, 2));

        // string list
        List<String> listString = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("abc", "xyz"));

        // nested lists.
        List nestedList = new ArrayList();
        nestedList.add(listInteger);
        nestedList.add(listString);
        nestedList.add("A");
    }
}
```

But ultimately, the solution in general is not good.
I don't have all your requirements, but a better idea would be to have an object to store all your collections and objects. You code would be cleaner and free from @SuppressWarnings, which are considered bad.

Something like:

```
MyObj myobj = new MyObj();
nestedList.setIntegers(listInteger);
nestedList.setStrings(listString);
nestedList.setSomeProperty("A");
```

Answer (score 2):

Making it `List<Object> = new ArrayList<>();` would allow you to add any type of Object regardless of type.

Comment: I'm not saying you're necessarily wrong, but now you have to do two casts - one to get the inner list, and one to get the object from the inner list.

Comment: @Makoto : Unless author want to use toString method to everything :) (which he probably does not)

Answer (score 0):

Just change this line

```
    List<List> nestedList = new ArrayList<List>();
```

And it is, because you are storing list in lists, the type is List :)

Comment: I'd make it a `List<List<?>>`.

Comment: But when you go to retrieve info from that list, it is typed with `Object` instead.

Comment: @Makoto - of course, thats the price of having different lists in list.

Comment: Yes, but something smells.  It doesn't make sense to have a list of list of objects.  It kind of feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/175248), you know?

Comment: @Makoto - well yeah, I would like to suggest another solution for author, but there is not enough info of what does he need.

Comment: In that case, asking for more information is best, not providing an answer on half-complete information.

Comment: `List<List<?>>` is the correct type.  It's OK that this is a list of lists of objects, because ultimately, you don't know, when you write `nestedList.get(i).get(j)`, what kind of object you're getting.  So it can't be a list of lists of anything more specific than `Object`.

Comment: @AlexandreSantos - of course, because if you set List generic type to List, you can insert only List.

If you are supposed to write a generic list class, you are doing something completely different. Just google for "generic class" and learn tutorials.